# Returning a String with line break from an Apex method (AuraEnabled)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a String being returned from an Apex method as follows,

```
public class TestController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getAddress(){
        Address userAddress = [Select Address from User where id =: UserInfo.getUserId()].Address;
        return userAddress.street + '\r\n' + userAddress.state;
    }
}
```

and I'm using this string to display the address in a lightning component.

The string displays with the address, but doesn't replace '\r\n' with a line break. I get the following output

```
Street State
```

I even tried using '< br/>' instead, which shows up as it is on the component

```
street< br/>state
```

I want to include the line break within the String being returned from the method.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: I've used `<br />`  in Visualforce, and then when you show the message in VF you need to add the `<apex:pageMessages ... escape="false" />`.  I know you aren't doing visualforce but there may be an equivalent

Comment: Excellent suggestion! There is indeed an Aura Tag that renders the string with unescaped html.

Comment: Sweet! Let me know if I can put this down as an answer

Comment: I was working on answering the question myself. Gave you the credit. If you want, please do post the answer, I'll accept that instead. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [EricSSH](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7015/ericssh)'s suggestion of escape="false", I did a quick search for any Aura tags that would escape HTML, and found
    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_unescapedHtml.htm

This did help me include a line break within a String with the use of '< br/>' and displaying it on the component as follows

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.yourString}" />
```

Comment: I've tried with aura:unescapedHtml tag.
But It's not working

Comment: This is working

Comment: If you're fetching your string from value in a text field via an apex controller, you'll need to use `myString.replace('\n', '<br/>')` to convert the line breaks into HTML.

Answer (score 4):

I needed a solution that didn't require modifying the string and found this to work in Chrome and Firefox.

`<pre>{!v.yourString}</pre>`

The `<pre/>` html tag diplays text in a fixed-width non-wrapped text, but the following CSS made it blend in with the rest of the page.

```
.THIS pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    font-family: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: This helped me quite a bit, thanks!  Quick note for posterity: when playing around, I found it wasn't actually necessary to use <pre>.  A standard <div> with the white-space and word-wrap CSS you applied worked for me, and didn't require the font-family to be overridden.